# trying to run the pi400 on battery/12v

Tags: pi-400

I have powered my Pi 3s and 4s successfully via 12 volts with various battery packs.

I'm trying to do the same with the PI400.  Has anyone successfully powered the Pi400 via 12v and if so, how?

thx

Comment: How are you trying to feed power into the Pi400?

Comment: Don't have anything yet.  I know how to do it with the Pi 4's.  There I have a connection from 12v battery run into a buck converter, and then the buck converter connected to the appropriate GIPO pins, but that's a no go on the Pi 400.

So ideally, I'd like some way to simply plug the PI 400 into an anderson power pole distro center hooked up to a 12v battery.  

The 400 comes with a 12v wall wart, so my thinking is the only way to power it would be to bring the power in through the USB C connection that is currently used for power.

Comment: Pi400 does not come with a 12V wall wart!

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT power the Pi400 through the power pins on the expansion header.
You need to use the power port.

---

NOTE the reference to 12V is irrelevant you need 5V (however derived).
All Pi run on 5V (actually the official supplies deliver 5.1V),